# Nginx + php-fpm returning either a blank page or "no input file specified"

Tags: php, nginx

I am using nginx with php5-fpm on a Debian stable system. Here is my default site:

```
server {
listen 443 default_server;
server_name _;

root /home/www/known;

# Deny access to dot files and dirs
location ~ /\. {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    deny all;
}

# Enable PHP for vhosts
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
location ~ \.php$ {
    # regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    # Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
    try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

    # Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
    # see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
    set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi.conf;

    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/phyks.me/root.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/phyks.me/root.key;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
}
```

The PHP part is taken from the php fastcgi snippet bundled with Nginx in Debian. The /home/www/known/index.php file exists and is readable by www-data (which both nginx and php-fpm runs as) but I get a "no input file specified" although the file path is passed correctly by nginx to php-fpm.

I tried to replace the content of the location block for php files by

```
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
```

In this case I have a blank page (with status 200) and cannot get any verbose output to the log, either from php5-fpm or nginx.

I have been stuck hours with this, trying different config options, but could not figure out what is going on… Do you have any ideas? Plus similar configuration works on other servers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Please check if your `/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf` or `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params` includes this `param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;` or else append it to file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @dhh: Please elaborate a little more since for poor nginx configurator that for example I am the answer seems like something that might actually work.

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04 both "fastcgi.conf and "fastcgi_params" are shipped.  The only difference is that fastcgi.conf includes the SCRIPT_FILENAME setting.  Switching the include line to "include fastcgi.conf;" pulls in the setting.  Quite annoying since no errors are logged by PHP FPM even with debug on.